# iPhone native application to iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

i would like to port my application (pure OpenGL ES based) on the iPad

currently it runs in ipad on some kind of compatibility mode, where i can scale it to 2x

however i want to have it native, not launching in 1 / 2 resolution (btw iam getting the screen size from the renderbuffer)

```
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in project properties, set the key **Target device family** to iPhone/iPad

Comment: ok, but there is no such property there, and if i try to add it (Target device family) its says that its not a valid name, since it contains space character

Comment: Just follow the steps, Project->Edit project settings->Build tab->select Release configuration->In search type Targeted device family